# Uniform Convergence of Covering Maps that cannot approach a constant map

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In the problem I'm looking at we are given a hyperbolic surface contained in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1\}$ and a sequence of points $z_1, z_2,...$ that approach some point on the boundary of this surface.

We can construct a family of covering maps $p_n : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0,1 \}$ such that $p_n(0)= z_n$ and $p_n (B(0,r)) = B(z_n, r)$ for some $r>0$ where $B(,)$ is a ball.

I want to show that the spherical diameters of these balls approach zero. Here's one of the arguments made in the proof I'm looking at:

"If they didn't approach zero, one could apply Montel's Theorem onto the subsequence that doesn't approach zero and that would imply they would converge locally uniformly to a constant map, which is impossible."

However, no further justification is made here and I'm a little confused on two things:

Why must it approach a constant map?

Why is it impossible for a subsequence of covering maps to converge locally uniformly to a constant map?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (The link to the proof I'm looking at can be found on page 23/24 here - https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/dozier/dozier.pdf)

Comment: The diameters do not approach $0$. You said the radii of the balls are all the same value $r$, so their diameters are all $2r$, a constant. Also, you talk about a "surface" and "spherical balls", but everything is occuring in $\Bbb C$, the complex **plane**. The $B(z_i, r)$ are disks, not spherical, and subsets of $\Bbb C$ are flat, not hyperbolic. It is apparent that the descriptions you provided here and the descriptions in your source must differ in significant details. Could you please *carefully* reproduce the actual descriptions from your source here?

Comment: I must admit I am still confused about the notation the source uses. The claim is: "for a hyperbolic surface $U \subset \widetilde{\mathbb{C}}$ and a sequence of points $z_1,z_2,...$ a sequence of points converging to a boundary points $z \in \partial U$ and given an $r>0$, the closed balls $B(z_n , r)$ converge uniformly to $z$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$" I agree that calling them balls although we are in the complex plane feels weird. The source says that the diameter of $B(z_n, r)$ approaches $0$ in the spherical metric, perhaps that could be the step I missed? Link to the source is in post.